# how to send request to an external url in yii2 action method

Tags: php, json, yii2

I have a web site which has written in php yii2 framework.
I have second one which is written in mvc.net which has an api for example called `www.secondone.com/api/get_records`. This api returns json and I want to use this `json` in my yii2 application action. 
What is the way to get content of an external url in yii2 action?

Comment: have a look at this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-curl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try curl

> CURL is a library that lets you make HTTP requests in PHP. Everything
>   you need to know about it (and most other extensions) can be found in
>   the PHP manual.
>
> ```
> In order to use PHP's cURL functions you need to install the » libcurl package. PHP requires that you use libcurl 7.0.2-beta or
> ```
>
> higher. In PHP 4.2.3, you will need libcurl version 7.9.0 or higher.
>   From PHP 4.3.0, you will need a libcurl version that's 7.9.8 or
>   higher. PHP 5.0.0 requires a libcurl version 7.10.5 or greater.
>
> You can make HTTP requests without cURL, too, though it requires
>   allow_url_fopen to be enabled in your php.ini file.

here's some code sample

```
$service_url = 'http://path/to/api.asmx/function_name';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(
        'param1' => 'val1',
        'param2' => 'val2'  
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
echo 'response ok!';
var_export($decoded->response);
```